# React Native: How to fix version issue in Gradle

Tags: java, android, react-native, gradle

I have a project that is on `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip`

But my local Gradle version is:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.4.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-04-26 08:14:42 UTC
Revision:     261d171646b36a6a28d5a19a69676cd098a4c19d

Kotlin:       1.3.21
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.13 compiled on July 10 2018
JVM:          1.8.0_201 (Oracle Corporation 25.201-b09)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.13.6 x86_64
```

I thought it would be a simple going to Android Studio, **File** -> **Project structure** and changing the Gradle version in there, I changed it from 5.1.1 to 4.10.1 according to what I have in `gradle-wrapper.properties
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip`, but then I got the error:

> Error “Minimum supported Gradle version is 5.1.1. Current version is
>   4.10.1” after update android studio

Does this mean I need to just bring everything up to date with 5.1.1?
If so, what is the best steps to take to get everything in this legacy gradle RN project up to speed with 5.1.1
the breaking changes documented here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_4.html#changes_5.0#preamble

I wish whats documented there were exactly what I am going through, but that would be too easy.

For example, this is one of the errors I continue to get:

`Task 'installDebug' not found in project ':app'. Some candidates are: 'installDevDebug', 'installQaDebug', 'installUaDebug'.`

I go into `android/` and run `gradle installDevDebug` and I end up with this error:

```
Task :react-native-sentry:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
/Users/danale/Projects/engage-application.mobile/node_modules/react-native-sentry/android/src/main/java/io/sentry/RNSentryModule.java:252: error: incompatible types: ReadableArray cannot be converted to ReadableNativeArray
            addExceptionInterface(eventBuilder, exception.getString("type"), exception.getString("value"), stacktrace.getArray("frames"));
                                                                                                                              ^
Note: /Users/danale/Projects/engage-application.mobile/node_modules/react-native-sentry/android/src/main/java/io/sentry/RNSentryModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-sentry:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the --stacktrace option when you run the command? Or changing the distributionUrl in the ProjectBuilder.js?

```
     var distributionUrl = process.env['CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL'] || 'https\\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip'; <<<<change to 4.10.1 here where the var is set.
```

Comment: Curtis, Curtis, are you referring to this `wrapper.properties
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip`? If so, I did change it there and ran it all again and got this error: `/node_modules/react-native-sentry/android/src/main/java/io/sentry/RNSentryModule.java:252: error: incompatible types: ReadableArray cannot be converted to ReadableNativeArray
            addExceptionInterface(eventBuilder, exception.getString("type"), exception.getString("value"), stacktrace.getArray("frames"));`